# Proving a statement about $k$-colouring of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Prove that a graph is $k$-colourable iff its edges can be oriented in such a way that the resulting directed graph does not contain a path of length $k$.

It seems to me that the '$\Leftarrow$' implication might be slightly easier to show if we were to consider directed *acyclic* graphs (then we could assign subsequent colors to vertices as we traverse along a path and do some rearranging when we visit an already coloured vertex)... But I am stuck at finding a valid argument that justifies the implication in either direction, not to mention I am actually interested in a stronger statement.

Answer (score 2):

For the forward direction, let the colors be $\{1,2,\ldots, k\}$ and orient each edge to go from the higher color to the lower one.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use the [Gallai-Hasse-Roy-Vitaver Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallai%E2%80%93Hasse%E2%80%93Roy%E2%80%93Vitaver_theorem).